# Syncronization of Multiple Js requests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous, promise, ngresource

I'm having some issues trying to synchronize multiple Async requests in AngularJS.
I'm going to explain what i have and what i need.

- User has many sites
- Each site has many subscriptions
- Each site has many transactions
- Each transaction is associated with a subscription

I'm getting the subscriptions and transactions through a 3rd party API. Each of them returns and Array of Elements who has the associated Id.
So i need to make a request for each of the elements of each array and associate both results.

I don't know what to do, or how i can handle this.
any help is appreciate.

```
$q.all([
    PaymentService.getTransactions(profile.payment.account_code),
    SiteService.getAll(),
    PaymentService.getUserSubscriptions(profile.payment.account_code)
  ]).then(function (data) {
    var transactions = data[0];
    var user_sites = data[1];
    var user_subscriptions = data[2];
    // returns site-by-site
    angular.forEach(user_sites, function (site) {
      SiteService.loadSite(site.$value).then(function (loaded_site) {
        loaded_site.transactions = [];
        loaded_site.subscriptions = [];
        angular.forEach(user_subscriptions, function (subscription) {
          console.log('SUBSCRIPTION: ', subscription);
          if ( subscription.uuid === loaded_site.recurly_subscription_uuid ) {
            loaded_site.subscriptions.push(subscription);
          }
        });
        angular.forEach(transactions, function (transaction) {
          if ( transaction.subscription ) {
            if ( getSubscriptionId(transaction.subscription.$.href) === loaded_site.recurly_subscription_uuid ) {
              loaded_site.transactions.push(transaction);
            }
          }
        });
        $scope.sites.push(loaded_site);
      });
    });
  })
```

Comment: what kind of "issues" are you having?

Comment: the main issue is i just have their uuids for each object and i need to retrieve those objects via http and then make a kind of merge between them to make an association, i don't know how i can achieve that or how can i synchronize those http calls

Answer (score 0):

You can reapply the `$q.all` technique:

```
$q.all([
    PaymentService.getTransactions(profile.payment.account_code),
    SiteService.getAll(),
    PaymentService.getUserSubscriptions(profile.payment.account_code)
  ]).then(function (data) {
    var transactions = data[0];
    var user_sites = data[1];
    var user_subscriptions = data[2];

    var promises = [];

    angular.forEach(user_sites, function (site) {
      promises.push(SiteService.loadSite(site.$value));
    });


    $q.all(promises).then(function(loaded_sites) {
      angular.forEach(loaded_sites, funciton(loaded_site) {

        loaded_site.transactions = [];
        loaded_site.subscriptions = [];


        angular.forEach(user_subscriptions, function (subscription) {
          console.log('SUBSCRIPTION: ', subscription);
          if ( subscription.uuid === loaded_site.recurly_subscription_uuid ) {
            loaded_site.subscriptions.push(subscription);
          }
        });

        angular.forEach(transactions, function (transaction) {
          if ( transaction.subscription ) {
            if ( getSubscriptionId(transaction.subscription.$.href) === loaded_site.recurly_subscription_uuid ) {
              loaded_site.transactions.push(transaction);
            }
          }
        });

        $scope.sites.push(loaded_site);

      });

     });

  });
```